# Django Profile not saving other fields with UserModel

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to have a school system that have different profiles for students, lecturer and others, which i was able to achieve by creating a custom userModel, however, i was unable to save other information (avatar, semester etc) from the form to the student profile when creating them.
its only the user_id that is getting saved in the studentProfile model.

I am using django signal to post this data as well as generic createView to render to the screen.

I have tried different means to solve this but still not saving other fields

my models.py

```
class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    semester = models.ForeignKey(SemesterData, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    dept_name = models.ForeignKey(DepartmentData, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars/', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        if instance.admin:
            pass
        else:
            data = StudentProfile.semester
            HttpResponse(data)
            StudentProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Here is my form.py

```
class UserAdminCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password."""
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    user_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=User.USER_TYPE_CHOICES,widget=forms.Select)
    # user_type = forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('user_id', 'first_name','last_name','user_type',)

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(UserAdminCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserAdminChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
    the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
    password hash display field.
    """
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('user_id','first_name','last_name', 'password', 'active', 'admin')

    def clean_password(self):
        # Regardless of what the user provides, return the initial value.
        # This is done here, rather than on the field, because the
        # field does not have access to the initial value
        return self.initial["password"]


class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    user_id = forms.CharField(label="User Id", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':'Enter Matric Num or Student Id'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)


class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password."""
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    # user_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=User.USER_TYPE_CHOICES, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), label="Select One", initial=User.USER_TYPE_CHOICES[1])


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('user_id', 'first_name', 'last_name',)
        widgets = {

            'user_id': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter Matric Num or Student Id '}),
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter First Name'}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter Last Name'}),
            # 'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter Department Name'}),
        }

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        # user = super(UserAdminCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        user.user_type = 1
        if commit:
            user.save()

            profile_form = ProfileForm(self.request.POST, instance=self.request.user.profile)
            profile_form.save()
        return user


class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    dept_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=DepartmentData.objects.all(), empty_label="Select One",
                                       widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), label="Select One")
    semester = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=SemesterData.objects.all(), empty_label="Select One",
                                      widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), label="Select One")
    avatar = forms.ImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = StudentProfile
        fields = "__all__"
```

this is my views.py

```
class RegisterView(CreateView):
    form_class = RegisterForm
    template_name = 'accounts/student/signup.html'
    success_url = '/login'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # app = settings.CONFIG
        table = FacultyTable(FacultyData.objects.all())
        RequestConfig(self.request, paginate={'per_page': 10}).configure(table)

        context = super(RegisterView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['app'] = settings.CONFIG
        context['faculty'] = table
        context['profile'] = ProfileForm
        return context
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'account'

urlpatterns = [
    path('register', RegisterView.as_view(), name ="signup"),
    path('register/student', RegisterView.as_view(), name="signup_student"),
    # path('signup', views.signup_view, name ="signup"),
    path('', LoginView.as_view(), name="login"),
    path('login', views.login_view, name ="login"),
    path('logout', views.logout_view, name ="logout"),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have in your `RegisterForm` a line like following in the save method:

```
profile_form = ProfileForm(self.request.POST, instance=self.request.user.StudentProfile)
```

Perhaps you look for data to `ProfileForm` in `self.cleaned_data`:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    # Save the provided password in hashed format
    user = super().save(commit=False)
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
    user.user_type = 1
    if commit:
        user.save()

        # Extract your profile data from self.cleaned_data
        profile_data = self.cleaned_data

        profile_form = ProfileForm(profile_data)

        profile_form.save()
    return user
```

in that line, `self` refers to the form itself, and therefore not have and an attribute `request`, it is a form, not a view.

Also, you should take a look into [FormSets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/formsets/)

On the other hand, I can see you're trying to do here.

My suggestion is to register a user as usual (`User` model, just email, username, password), and then, on successful registration, redirect to a page where you can/must customize your profile (a page containing a `ProfileForm` to gather the profile data and create the corresponding `StudentProfile`) and at this point you already have the related user instance in `request.user`.

Comment: you are right but I was trying to save time for the admin by doing everything at once.   Is there a way i can get these fields from another function after registering the user - so probably instead of redirection,  it calls the next function

Comment: I know, I've just update the answer in order to show you a possible solution